# What are the differences between learning by analogy, inductive learning and explanation based learning?

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

I have heard of the concepts of *learning by analogy* (which is quite self-explanatory), *inductive learning* and *explanation-based learning*. I tried to learn about [inductive learning](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/AI2/node144.html#SECTION000161000000000000000) and [explanation-based learning](http://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/AI2/node148.html), but I don't understand them.

How would you explain all these three concepts? What are the differences between them?

A link to some explanatory article/notes/blog post are appreciated too.

Comment: Classical machine learning seem to fall into  inductive learning. While explanation learning looks like a mixture of the process used in NLP with absurly large data augmentation